# Getting a value from JCombo

Tags: laravel-5, jcombobox

i used jcombo to get all the values for dropdowns and it works fine.. Filters work fine too... I get all the values i need in dropdown. I have been trying to use the value that i get with jcombo in the page but i couldnt.. i need to create an input mask.. i need the value total_capacity in tourdateID to use for input mask.. i can see the value in dropdown but i failed to get it in the page.. any idea? thanks alot

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        $("#tourcategoriesID").jCombo("{!! url('booking/comboselect?filter=def_tour_categories:tourcategoriesID:tourcategoryname') !!}",
        {  selected_value : '{{ $row["tourcategoriesID"] }}' });

        $("#tourID").jCombo("{!! url('booking/comboselect?filter=tours:tourID:tour_name') !!}&parent=tourcategoriesID:",
        {  parent: '#tourcategoriesID', selected_value : '{{ $row["tourID"] }}' });

        $("#tourdateID").jCombo("{!! url('booking/comboselect?filter=tour_date:tourdateID:tour_code|start|total_capacity') !!}&parent=tourID:",
        {  parent: '#tourID', selected_value : '{{ $row["tourdateID"] }}' });
```

..

```
<div class="form-group  " >
<label for="ipt" class=" control-label "> Tour Date  <span class="asterix"> * </span>  </label>                                 
<select name='tourdateID' rows='5' id='tourdateID' class='select2 ' required  ></select>                        
</div>
```